# Why do CLI commands return no errors/exceptions?

Tags: magento-2.1, error, exception, cli, command-line

**Problem:**

I'm writing a custom module, and everything is output just fine when there are no errors/exceptions.  But as soon as I experience an error, nothing is displayed in the command line (using SSH via PuTTY to a shared host).  It just executes the command, outputs nothing, and returns to the prompt.

Also, nothing is being written to any of the usual server logs within "/var/logs".

I'm basically flying blind.  I don't know why things fail when they do, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

**Example:**

```
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command with the verbose flag

```
-v
-vv 
-vvv
-vvvv
```

Depending on the level of verboseness (not a real word) you need.

Comment: I just tried this with no luck.  Any other ideas?

`sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list -v
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list -vv
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list -vvv
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]# php /home/sharedhostingname/public_html/bin/magento --list -vvvv
sharedhostingname@sharedhost [~]#`

Comment: the next thing to check would be clearing everything in the var folder. I use this `rm -rf var/cache/*; rm -rf var/di/*; rm -rf var/generation/*; rm -rf var/page_cache/*;` to for a clean of these folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.  For example, I've placed a tiny bit of bad code in one line of my PHP file.  It should be telling me that some kind of exception occurred on line X, but I get no output at all, not even partial up to the point that it breaks.

Comment: are you in `developer` mode and do you have php errors turned on? It's really odd behavior, and something i have never come across. There are time when the CLI will and wont work for different reasons, but when it fails, it has always given me an error. if you have php errors, that should show up on the site even if the CLI doesn't reflect it.

Comment: No, this is on shared hosting, so I'm in production mode with errors turned off.  I know that's not ideal, but it's the best I've got at the moment.  PHP errors are displayed in the logs when triggered on web pages, but this CLI command thing has me baffled.  I appreciate your help!  Could it possibly be something my web host has disabled?  I'm wondering if I should be thinking about switching hosts...

Comment: It is definitely the next thing to check, but that doesn't mean that it is actually the cause. No one recommends running M2 on a shared hosting set up, i think less because they know it doesn't work and more because it's just the way everyone talks about it. I would recommend setting up a local install of the site using a VM or MAMP (WAMP or XAMP) and see if you get the same error. No sense in moving hosting only to find that wasn't the issue all along.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Much appreciated.  I'll try that when I get some time.

Comment: I had the same issue and I discovered that there was a code that caught the exception and passed to the messageManager but in the CLI environment it couldn't show the error so the exception was hided. I think you have maybe the same kind of problem.

Comment: You should actually check the error_log file on magento root which will give out errors for CLI runtime errors.

It was memory shortfall for me PHP CLI.